# What's wrong in my code? javafx tableview does not show data from database

Tags: javafx

**javafx** tableview does not show data from **database**

```
`public class packList` {

Stage primaryStage;
```

private TableView tbl = new TableView();

private TableColumn pSerial = new TableColumn<>("Serial No.");

private TableColumn pName = new TableColumn<>("Package Name");

```
private TableColumn<Packaged, String> pSpeed = new TableColumn<>("Speed");

private TableColumn<Packaged, String> pMonthlyFee = new TableColumn<>("Monthly Fee");

private TableColumn<Packaged, String> pConnection = new TableColumn<>("Connection Fee");

private TableColumn<Packaged, String> pOther = new TableColumn<>("Others");

private TableColumn<Packaged, String> pView = new TableColumn<>("View");
```

private TableColumn pEdit = new TableColumn<>("Edit");

private TableColumn pDelete = new TableColumn<>("Delete");

```
private Packaged packaged = new Packaged();
private PackageController packageController = new PackageController();
private ArrayList<Packaged> packagedList = new ArrayList<>();
private ObservableList<Packaged> ps;

public packList(Stage stage) {

    this.primaryStage = stage;
    this.primaryStage.show();
    this.primaryStage.setScene(AllpackList());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Scene AllpackLis() {

    StackPane mainPane = new StackPane();
    mainPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    StackPane pane = new StackPane();
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    // empName.prefWidthProperty().bind(tbl.widthProperty().multiply(10));
    packagedList = packageController.getAllPackage();
    ps = FXCollections.observableArrayList(packagedList);

    pSerial.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pkg_id"));
    pName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pkg_name"));
    pSpeed.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("speed"));
    pMonthlyFee.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("mFee"));
    pView.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("view"));
    pEdit.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("edit"));
    pDelete.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("delete"));

    tbl.setItems(ps);

    StackPane.setMargin(tbl, new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));

    tbl.getColumns().addAll(pSerial, pName, pSpeed, pMonthlyFee, pView, pEdit, pDelete);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(tbl);

    // StackPane.setMargin(pane, new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));
    pane.getStyleClass().add("pane");

    mainPane.getChildren().addAll(pane);
    return Common.returnScene(mainPane);
  }
}
```

`and java class is` :

public class 'Packaged' {

```
private int pkgId;
private String pkgName;
private String pkgSpeed;
private String pkgCFee;
private String pkgMFee;

public int getPkgId() {
    return pkgId;
}

public void setPkgId(int pkgId) {
    this.pkgId = pkgId;
}

public String getPkgName() {
    return pkgName;
}

public void setPkgName(String pkgName) {
    this.pkgName = pkgName;
}

public String getPkgSpeed() {
    return pkgSpeed;
}

public void setPkgSpeed(String pkgSpeed) {
    this.pkgSpeed = pkgSpeed;
}

public String getPkgCFee() {
    return pkgCFee;
}

public void setPkgCFee(String pkgCFee) {
    this.pkgCFee = pkgCFee;
}

public String getPkgMFee() {
    return pkgMFee;
}

public void setPkgMFee(String pkgMFee) {
    this.pkgMFee = pkgMFee;
}
```

}

Comment: Most probably `Packaged` does not have the needed accessor methods used by `PropertyValueFactory` (or `packagedList` is empty). Please post `Packaged`class.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and change your example :)

Comment: Also I consider it bad practice to use class names as method names: The naming convention for java suggests lower case method names. You can easily get confused with the method names if you choose them like you did, since there also is a constructor with the same name it's easy to mix them up.